# Facebook payment dialogue not working. Trouble processing your payment

Tags: facebook, dialog, payment

I try to configure application for facebook, but have troubles with facebook payment function. JS SDK give me anwer.

"Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again."

I uploaded screenshots, with all information.

ERROR
http://screencast.com/t/PoSAVUi4 
MY CODE
http://screencast.com/t/evS1DzvIcBlC
FACEBOOK APP SETTINGS
http://screencast.com/t/bh2oAjolV0zU 
CREDITS SETINGS
http://screencast.com/t/i2vocbXftLA

Answer (score 0):

Your callback immediately redirects to http://www.local.com - check that out first - if your callback can't be properly reached by Facebook it's not going to work